# Seblod: How to make url redirection happen only if the captcha is verified?

Tags: joomla

Using Seblod I created a form where users can enter their name, email id and captcha. They can view next page only when they fill this correctly. To go to next page, I gave url redirection feature (site form->configuration).

But now page redirects to next page even if user enters wrong captcha. How to make the redirection happen only when entered captcha is correct?

Answer (score 0):

There will be an `if` statement for the captcha so that if it's correct, it moves on, else nothing happens and the captcha resets.

The code to redirect the user after submitting the form will need to go inside the `if` statement.

Open recaptchalib.php and go to line 184, where you will see the following:

```
if (trim ($answers [0]) == 'true') {
      $recaptcha_response->is_valid = true;
      //Redirect Code
}
```

Where I have added the comment, try adding in your redirect code